# Not Able to find single element in Appium inspector IOS automation

Tags: react-native, automation, react-native-navigation, appium-ios, react-navigation-bottom-tab

This is how stack looks in the mobile app and functionality is working fine.

```
Main Stack:       \<MainStack.Navigator\>      \<MainStack.Screen name={dashboard} component={DashboardStackScreen} /\>           \</MainStack.Navigator\>  DashBoard Stack:       \<DashboardStack.Navigator\>       \<DashboardStack.Screen name={"bottomtabs"} component={bottomTab} /\>         \</DashboardStack.Navigator\>  Tab Navigator      \<Tab.Navigator\> \<Tab.Screen name={"home"} component={stackhome} /\>      \<Tab.Screen name={"profile"}     component={profileStack} /\>       \</Tab.Navigator\>
```

The issue is, Appium is not able able to inspect elements on screen in IOS automation.        Also, when i directly call this Tab navigator to main stack, i am able to inspect elements, but in that case     Appium is not able to inpect single  bottom tabs.     Any assistant would be helpful.